# why my element.right + element.left is more than screen.width in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show popup div with absolute position on top of the element clicked.
but the pop up shown on wrong position (in responsive size). when I `console.log(rect.left)` and `console.log(rect.right)`, the sum of these are more `screen.width`

here is the popup function:

```
 function show_popup(element){
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.table(rect);
    console.log('rect left : ' + rect.left);
    console.log('rect right: ' + rect.right);
    console.log('screen width :' + screen.width);
    x = (rect.right - ( $('#popup').width() / 2 ));
    x = x < 0 ? 0 : x ;
    $('#popup').css({right :  x  , bottom: 90 });
    $('#popup').fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(() => {
         $('#popup').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 3500);
}
```

the popup css :

```
.popup {
display: none;
background-color:rgb(248, 248, 87);
position: fixed;
z-index: 1050;
padding: 0.4rem;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

I have had this problem for two weeks,
how can I solve that?
how can I get the correct `right` for show the popup?

thanks in advance

Comment: The *difference* between `right` and `left` should be less than the screen width, not the *sum*. If you consider a rect just to the left of the right edge of the screen, both `left` and `right` will be > `screen.width/2`, so their sum will be > `screen.width`

Comment: Your code does not correspond to your description (there is no console.log involving right). Please make a more complete and runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why do you even look at `screen.width`? Is your page full-screen? Apart from the logs there is nothing in your snippet about the sum of right and left, which as has been said wouldn't mean much anyway, since `left` + `right` ==  `(left * 2) + width`. Please clarify your question.